# How to do a proper session logout from https to http?

Tags: php, session, logout

I have a webpage that switches to HTTPS upon login and back to HTTP upon logout. To enhance security, the session cookie is set to secure (HTTPS) upon login. My logout page is [pretty standard](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), having the following code:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION = array();
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(), "", time() - 42000, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], $params['httponly']);

session_destroy();
require("/var/www/include/logout_success.php");
```

I didn't think much about the implications until recently when I started to look at the response headers. It now appears to me that calling `session_start()` when the page switches back to HTTP creates a new session cookie that overrides the secure cookie.

This means that `setcookie` and `session_destroy` might be acting upon the new session instead of the old one. I am more concern that the old session data residing in my server may not be properly destroyed.

In this case, how does one goes about coding the HTTP logout page to ensure that the old session data is really destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a `require` to include the "logout success" content, do a `Header("Location: http://domain/path-to-logout-success.php")`.

Once the HTTPS negotiation has occurred, you can't set a cookie for the "other" protocol. Only once the user's browser requests the "other" protocol can you set a cookie for it.

Comment: Ah.. do you mean that I still keep it as HTTPS on logout until after the redirection?

Comment: Yes. The page should still be HTTPS before you do `session_start()`. Doing `session_end()` does nothing to change that. When you redirect to HTTP, either establish another session there, or just do nothing.

Comment: Ok, nice solution. I think I will adopt it. Thanks :)